# Does laravel handle foreign keys on its own

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have watched tutorials and have seen them access an id of another table which is inserted automatically which am sure would be through the model relationships. The migration look something like this

### migrations

```
   $table->id();
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
```

where `'post_id` is an id of another table. Would doing that be the same as making a foreign key like below

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what the problem is you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel assumes the foreign key to be singular table name + _id e.g user_id for users table but you can override this when defining relationships in the model like:

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'<some other name>','id');
}
```